# itextsharp - AcroForm field value disappears after signing PDF document

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

the following szenario is given: party 1 signs pdf, party 2 fills out AcroForm field and then also signs the pdf.
The problem is, after the second signature, the form field value only appears if I click in the field. Both the form filling process and the signature process happen in append mode.
signing pdf code:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', tempFolder, true))
{
    // Creating the signature
    SigPadSignature sig = new SigPadSignature(sigInfo, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);

    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    appearance.Reason = sigInfo.Reason;
    appearance.Location = sigInfo.Location;
    appearance.Contact = sigInfo.ContactInfo;
    appearance.Certificate = chain[0];
    appearance.SignatureCreator = sigInfo.SignatureCreator;
    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(area.CreateRectangle(), area.PageNumber, fieldName);
    appearance.Layer2Text = string.Format("\n{0}\n{1}, {2:g}", sigInfo.SignerName, sigInfo.Location, DateTime.Now);
    appearance.Layer2Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 7.0f);
    appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
    appearance.SignatureGraphic = Image.GetInstance(sigInfo.SignatureImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    appearance.SignatureEvent = sig;

    MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, sig, chain, /*crlList*/null, /*ocspClient*/null, /*tsaClient*/null, estimatedSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

fill form field code:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStrm, '\0', true))
{
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField("fieldname", "test1234");
}
```

Here is a example [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/105iPaoWYKN8Mk4srds_ntMkGLo4XMrrm/view?usp=sharing). If you open it in AdobeReader you can see the szenario described. The form field value only appears when clicking the field.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In short

You actually discovered a bug in iTextSharp v5.x (also in iText v5.x and OpenPdf). When working in append mode in this library, one must mark each indirect object from the original file one manipulated as 'used' but iText(Sharp) forgets to do so for one object in the context of changing the field appearance.

This object needs not be indirect, actually it more often is direct or absent than indirect; thus, this bug does not have a visible effect very often.

You can work around this by removing that object in its previous form before setting setting the field value:

```cs
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStrm, '\0', true))
{
    stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem("AcroFormField_0").GetWidget(0).Remove(PdfName.AP);
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField("AcroFormField_0", "test1234");
}
```

(Actually some `null` checks wouldn't hurt here either...)

#### In detail

When setting the field value, eventually `AcroFields.SetField(String name, String value, String display, bool saveAppearance)` is called. In case of a text field, the new appearance of that field is updated in that method by this code:

```cs
PdfAppearance app = GetAppearance(merged, display, name);
...

PdfDictionary appDic = widget.GetAsDict(PdfName.AP);
if (appDic == null) {
    appDic = new PdfDictionary();
    widget.Put(PdfName.AP, appDic);
    merged.Put(PdfName.AP, appDic);
}

appDic.Put(PdfName.N, app.IndirectReference);
writer.ReleaseTemplate(app);
```

If there was no appearance dictionary before, a new one is created as direct object and everything works as desired. If there was an appearance dictionary as direct object, it's just the same as the `widget` is marked used further down. But if there was an appearance dictionary `appDict` as indirect object, this dictionary is not marked used and, therefore, the change (`appDic.Put(PdfName.N, app.IndirectReference)`) is not eventually saved, i.e. the new appearance is not associated with the field widget.

A fix would be to mark a previously existing appearance dictionary as used, e.g. like this:

```cs
if (appDic == null) {
    ...
} else {
    MarkUsed(appDic);
}
```

By removing it first as proposed above one makes iText create a new appearance dictionary as direct object, so the bug is circumvented.

#### And what about the signatures...?

It looks like Adobe Reader recognizes that the previous processor forgot to update the appearance and so does that itself under the hood in case of the PDF in which as last action the field value was set.

After adding another signature to that PDF, though, Adobe Reader apparently does not want to do this under the hood anymore. This would after all change what the signer had seen when signing, and Adobe tries to prevent such situations in which its software could be blamed for changing previously signed data...